# How can install cpp compiler on Ubuntu terminal

Tags: c++, compilation

How can install cpp compiler on Ubuntu terminal. 
The system says" * g++ 
* Pentium-builder 
Try: Sudo apt-get install i have been searched in google . I can't get a complete answer.

Comment: Sudo apt-get install g++?

Comment: I don't know what is that

Comment: This is how you install c++ compiler.

Comment: Yes..can you please give a suggestion?

Comment: Write sudo apt-get install g++ to your terminal

Comment: question is more suitable for https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Ok then the terminal says

Comment: Ok then the terminal says reading package lists... Done the following packages where automatically installed and are no longer required: libqt4-test libqt4-help python-qt4 python-sip libqtassistantclient4 libqt4-scripttools use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 to upgrade"?

Comment: Thank you friends!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Do the following steps:**

1. Open your terminal (or) command-line window.
2. Type the following command and then press ENTER

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. It will ask for the password. Type your `sudo` user password and press ENTER
4. Then type the following command and then press ENTER again.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install g++
   ```

This will install the `g++` compiler in `Ubuntu`

Comment: After that the system want to restart?

Comment: No need. After installation type the command `dpkg --list | grep compiler` and then press ENTER. If `g++` is installed successfully it will be shown on the compiler list. In case it does not show then restart the system and try again.

Comment: The terminal shows something like        ii gcc.            ii gcc-4.6  etc..

Comment: Yes, that's good then. `g++` is installed successfully.

Comment: But it will not work

Comment: After i type dpkg -- list | grep compiler .. It works but u cant compile a program right now